# Pig Load How to mix scalar and map datatypes?

Tags: apache-pig

Using Apache Pig version 0.10.1.21 (rexported)

Content of data sample file:

```
AtomicNumber,ElementName,Symbol,AtomicMass,PropertyMap
46,Palladium,Pd,106.42,[P#46,N#60,Struc#Cubic]
49,Indium,In,114.818,[P#49,N#66,Struc#Tetragonal]
52,Tellurium,Te,127.6,[P#52,N#76,Struc#Hexagonal]
86,Radon,222.0,Rn,[P#86,N#136,Struc#Cubic]
38,Strontium,Sr,87.62,[P#38,N#50,Struc#Cubic]
Plutonium,94,Pu,244.0,[P#94,N#150,Struc#Monoclinic]
```

NOTE: Some columns are swapped intentionally (for Radon and Plutonium) to see how Pig handle datatype mismatch

Pig script:

```
AtomElem = LOAD 'data/Atoms.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (AtomicNumber:int, ElementName:chararray, Symbol:chararray, AtomicMass:float, PropertyMap:map[]);
DUMP AtomElem;
```

Results:

```
(,ElementName,Symbol,,)
(46,Palladium,Pd,106.42,)
(49,Indium,In,114.818,)
(52,Tellurium,Te,127.6,)
(86,Radon,222.0,,)
(38,Strontium,Sr,87.62,)
(,94,Pu,244.0,)
```

**Question1**: I was hoping that the PropertyMap would be displayed. Can you please show me how to modify either the pig script or the data file in order to display the PropertyMap colum as map datatype.

**Question2**: In the declaration of the map schema, I would like to strong type the datatype. I declared the schema as PropertyMap:map[int, int, chararray] but pig had rejected the syntax (error on , right bracket expected). Is it possible to declare a map having several keys? If yes, what should the schema declaration look like?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script does not successfully produce the map is that you have used comma as your field delimeter, but it is also the delimeter for map key-value pairs.  So when Pig splits your line into fields, the fifth field is not `[P#46,N#60,Struc#Cubic]`, as you expect, but rather it is `[P#46`.  Pig cannot successfully parse this as a map, so it is converted to `NULL`.

As to your second question, you cannot specify the datatypes of individual map values.  In the first place, order means nothing in a map.  And a map can have any number of elements.  If you want to specify a single datatype for all your values, you can do so, but beyond that either Pig will figure out what type it is or you will need to explicitly cast the value when you use it.

To illustrate both of these points, I have modified your input data to be tab-delimited (and accordingly updated the script to be `USING PigStorage('\t')`), and swapped the position of two map elements in the second line to show that Pig does not reproduce the order they were provided in.

```
$ cat data.txt
AtomicNumber    ElementName     Symbol  AtomicMass      PropertyMap
46      Palladium       Pd      106.42  [P#46,N#60,Struc#Cubic]
49      Indium  In      114.818 [N#66,Struc#Tetragonal,P#49]
52      Tellurium       Te      127.6   [P#52,N#76,Struc#Hexagonal]
86      Radon   222.0   Rn      [P#86,N#136,Struc#Cubic]
38      Strontium       Sr      87.62   [P#38,N#50,Struc#Cubic]
Plutonium       94      Pu      244.0   [P#94,N#150,Struc#Monoclinic]

$ cat test.pig
AtomElem = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (AtomicNumber:int, ElementName:chararray, Symbol:chararray, AtomicMass:float, PropertyMap:map[]);
DUMP AtomElem;

$ pig -x local test.pig
(,ElementName,Symbol,,)
(46,Palladium,Pd,106.42,[P#46,N#60,Struc#Cubic])
(49,Indium,In,114.818,[P#49,N#66,Struc#Tetragonal])
(52,Tellurium,Te,127.6,[P#52,N#76,Struc#Hexagonal])
(86,Radon,222.0,,[P#86,N#136,Struc#Cubic])
(38,Strontium,Sr,87.62,[P#38,N#50,Struc#Cubic])
(,94,Pu,244.0,[P#94,N#150,Struc#Monoclinic])
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you very much for taking the time to rewrite my test case. It works perfectly. Understood for the clarification about Q2.

Comment: can you please help me a little bit more? I use this script to display the values from the map but get Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '#'. Sorry, but how can I type a code in this comment section?!?!?

Comment: Try asking a new question and posting exactly your code and data.  It sounds like the error is referring to a number sign in your code.

Comment: Hi, no need it was syntax error. The keyname must be surrounded by single quote. I instead of PropertyMap#P AS Proton I should type PropertyMap#'P' AS Proton.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd store all the data as JSON and load from that. When you have complicated data structures in your loaded data set, it'll make things much easier to manage for you and anyone working on this afterwards because JSON is a much more straight forward standard for nested structures than loading maps, etc... in pig.

I think @WinnieNicklaus' answer should work as well, but the next guy working on this, or the next time you need to add something complicated to your data, you'll run into the same problem. Just store everything in JSON and load with [Pig's Built-in JSON loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore):

```
a = load 'a.json' using 
JsonLoader('a0:int,a1:{(a10:int,a11:chararray)},a2:(a20:double,a21:bytearray),a3:[chararray]');
```

If you don't want to provide a schema, you can also load using ElephantBird's JSON loader:

```
loaded = LOAD '/path/to/some_file.json'
    using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');
```

Both of those should work fine with .gz files if I remember correctly, and the elephantbird version works with lzos as well.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting JSON loader. Will definitely try that when I get more familiar with Pig Latin.